# RegExp - точки, замена точек на запятые

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет.
Ребята, такой вопрос.
Как в регулярке, хотя бы в такой

```
RegExp('[^\\d]|[\\s]', 'g')
```

добавить возможность использования еще и точки для ввода, а если вводят запятую или -, то заменять на точку?

У меня есть код

```
inText.value = inText.value.replace( new RegExp( '[^\\d]|[\\s]', 'g' ), '' );
```

хочу сделать так, чтобы если вписали точку, то нормально, а если запятая или черточка, то заменяло на точку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одним выражением в JavaScript это не решимо. Делайте так:

```
text.replace(/[^\\d.,-]/g, "").replace(/[,-]/g, ".");
```

**upd**
Очистка от всего кроме букв:

```
text1.replace(/[^a-zа-я]/g, "");
```

Проверка на число с плавающей точкой:

```
text2.replace(/(.)[,-]/g, "\\1.").replace(/^.*?(-?\\d+(?:\.\\d*)?).*$/, "\\1");
```

Answer (score 1):

А почему не два регекспа?
Сначала `RegExp('[,\\.\\-]', 'g')` заменить на точку, а затем `RegExp('[^\\d]|[\\s]|\\.', 'g')`.

Comment: Я не очень в этом разбираюсь
у меня есть ко
    inText.value = inText.value.replace(new RegExp('[^\\d]|[\\s]', 'g'), '');
хочу сделать так, чтобы если вписали точку, то нормально. если запятая или черточка, то заменяло на точку.

Answer (score 1):

```
/(\d+)[\.\,\-]?(\d+)?/\1.\2/
```

Почему бы не предположить, что:

- целая часть числа всегда присутствует **(\d+)**
- за ней ВОЗМОЖНО следует точка, запятая или минус **[\.\,\-]?**
- и после неё ВОЗМОЖНО есть еще цифры **(\d+)?**

После чего подставить значение первой скобки, точку, значение второй скобки **\1.\2** Единственным недостатком будет то, что даже если в дробной части ничего не будет, после целой все равно будет стоять точка.

Answer (score 0):

Объясните смысл этого: `'[^\\d]|[\\s]'`

как по мне, так достаточно `[^\\d]` потому что в `[^\\d]` уже входит: `[\\s]`

Если вам нужно просто выделить число из строки, то можно сделать что то вроде этого:

```
var R = new RegExp('(\\d+)([,.]?)(\\d*)', 'g');
var str = '1999,89';
var num = str.replace(R, function(str, p1, p2, p3, offset, s){
    if (p3=='') return p1;
    return p1+'.'+p3;
});
alert(num);
```

Comment: я изначально не правильно определил. прошу прощения.
1 - нужно одно поле чистить от всего кроме букв azая.
2 - нужно второе поле проверять на число с плавающей точкой и без. т.е. если ввели 10 или 10.10 то нормально. если ввели 10,10 или 10-10 то заменять запятую и черточку на точку.

Comment: @shurik, \s -- пробелы, \d -- цифры, одно в другое никак не входит
@dropoff, для фильтра букв надежнее всего будет тупо перечислить все возможные буквы в квадратных скобках, типа [AB...XYZab...xyzАБВ...Яфбв...я].

Comment: @dropoff, читаем внимательно:

`'[^\\d]|[\\s]'`

первое всё кроме цифр, второе пробельные символы.

Мой ответ подойдет для второго пункта.